# GLIBC error while cross compiling gst-rtsp-server

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, arm, cross-compiling, glibc

I am trying to cross compile gst-rtsp-server for raspberrypi using raspbian tool chain downloaded from raspberry official site.

But I am getting following compiling errors. How can this be resolved?

```
echo "  CCLD    " test-video;/bin/bash ../libtool --silent --tag=CC   --mode=link /home/aneeshyarkm/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -std=gnu99 -I.. -I.. -pthread -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -pthread -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wold-style-definition -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Waddress -Waggregate-return -Wno-multichar -Wnested-externs   -g    -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wold-style-definition -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Waddress -Waggregate-return -Wno-multichar -Wnested-externs   -g    -I/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/gstreamer-1.0   -o test-video test-video.o ../gst/rtsp-server/libgstrtspserver-1.0.la -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0   -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0  
  CCLD     test-video
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/libdl.so.2: undefined reference to `_dl_catch_error@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/librt.so.1: undefined reference to `__pthread_get_minstack@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/libresolv.so.2: undefined reference to `__resolv_context_get@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/libm.so.6: undefined reference to `__strtod_nan@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/aneeshyarkm/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libglib-2.0.so: undefined reference to `getauxval@GLIBC_2.16'
/home/aneeshyarkm/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libglib-2.0.so: undefined reference to `posix_spawn@GLIBC_2.15'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/librt.so.1: undefined reference to `__clock_settime@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/aneeshyarkm/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.so: undefined reference to `__fdelt_chk@GLIBC_2.15'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/librt.so.1: undefined reference to `__clock_getcpuclockid@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/libresolv.so.2: undefined reference to `__resolv_context_get_preinit@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/librt.so.1: undefined reference to `__socket@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/librt.so.1: undefined reference to `__clock_nanosleep@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/libdl.so.2: undefined reference to `_dl_signal_error@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/libresolv.so.2: undefined reference to `__sendmmsg@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/libresolv.so.2: undefined reference to `__resolv_context_put@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/librt.so.1: undefined reference to `__pthread_barrier_init@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/libresolv.so.2: undefined reference to `__h_errno@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/libm.so.6: undefined reference to `__strtof_nan@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/aneeshyarkm/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libglib-2.0.so: undefined reference to `clock_gettime@GLIBC_2.17'
/home/aneeshyarkm/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libgio-2.0.so: undefined reference to `fcntl64@GLIBC_2.28'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/libmount.so.1: undefined reference to `setns@GLIBC_2.14'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/librt.so.1: undefined reference to `__pthread_barrier_wait@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/libmount.so.1: undefined reference to `scandirat64@GLIBC_2.15'
/home/aneeshyarkm/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libgio-2.0.so: undefined reference to `sendmmsg@GLIBC_2.14'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/libmount.so.1: undefined reference to `secure_getenv@GLIBC_2.17'
/home/aneeshyarkm/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libglib-2.0.so: undefined reference to `posix_spawnp@GLIBC_2.15'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/librt.so.1: undefined reference to `__libc_pread@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/libmount.so.1: undefined reference to `getrandom@GLIBC_2.25'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/librt.so.1: undefined reference to `__clock_getres@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/librt.so.1: undefined reference to `__shm_directory@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/librt.so.1: undefined reference to `__recv@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/librt.so.1: undefined reference to `__close_nocancel@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/librt.so.1: undefined reference to `fcntl@GLIBC_2.28'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/libresolv.so.2: undefined reference to `__resolv_context_get_override@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/aneeshyarkm/aneeshya/raspberry/missing_libraries/librt.so.1: undefined reference to `__clock_gettime@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:654: recipe for target 'test-video' failed
```